# rCharts and nvd3: how to programmatically call the 'magnify' function?

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts

I am using the awesome rCharts nvd3 charting utilities in R shiny(a **scatterChart** plot). I am using a custom tooltip as well as renderChart2:

```
output$mychart <- renderChart2({
    #...
    n1 <- nPlot(...)
    n1$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(key, x, y, e){ 
             return 'custom tooltip'
    } !#")
    return(n1)
  })
```

However, I notice that the mouseover / tooltips only start to work *after* I have clicked the 'magnify' radio button on the plot at least once:

[image: magnify button]

This is the case in both firefox and chrome. This does not seem to happen with barchart plots. (haven't investigated other chart types)

Is there a way to programmatically toggle the 'magnify' option once, right after rendering, so that tooltips are effective immediately? Sorry for the convoluted question - hope it makes sense.